# 3D math with QT: Create a view matrix

Tags: c++, qt, math, matrix, 3d

I'm trying to transform 3D coordinates into screen space with Qt's 4x4 Matrix.

This is the setup:

```
QVector3D pointx(0.5,0,0);

QMatrix4x4* mat=new QMatrix4x4();
mat->lookAt({1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,1,0});
*mat=mat->inverted();

pointx=mat->map(pointx);
```

It is a single point, positioned on the x-Axis.

The Matrix is created by lookAt. It's at (1,0,0) on the x-Axis and looks at the origin of the coordinate system. Up is the y-Direction.
This is the transformation matrix of the camera. In order to get the view matrix, I invert this.

The multiplication of the view matrix with the point should return (0,0, 0.5). The x and y coordinates are centered, the point is at a depth of 0.5. The actual result is: (1,0,-0.5).

I tried this with another setup: Camera along the z-Achsis, three points in the x-y plane:

```
QVector3D pointx(0.5,0,0);
QVector3D pointy(0,0.5,0);
QVector3D pointz(0,0,0.5);

QMatrix4x4* mat=new QMatrix4x4();
mat->setToIdentity();
mat->lookAt({0,0,1},{0,0,0},{0,1,0});
*mat=mat->inverted();

pointx=mat->map(pointx);
pointy=mat->map(pointy);
pointz=mat->map(pointz);
```

This delivers the correct result:

[image: x-y plane]

This plot just discards the z-coordinate.

What am I doing wrong ?
Is lookAt already inverted in Qt ?

Comment: Have you actually tried to remove the inversion? `lookAt` should return a ready-to-use view matrix.

Comment: You're right. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it